# Limiting Window Size and/or Removing Specific Rows of Time Values In R

Tags: r, time

I'm trying to figure out how to observe just one particular section of the data in the graph below (e.g. 5pm onwards). I know there are basically two methods of doing this:

**1) Method 1: Limiting the window size, which requires the following function:**

< symbols(Data$Times, Data$y, circles=Data$z, xlim=c("5:00pm","10:00pm"))

The problem is, I get an "invalid 'xlim' value" error when I try to input the two time endpoints.

**2)  Method 2: Clearing out the rows in Data$Times that have values over 5pm.**

The problem here is that I'm not sure how to sort the rows by earliest time -> latest time OR how to define a new variable such that TimesPM <- Data$Times>"5pm" (what I typed just now obviously did not work.)

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

ETA: This is what I plotted:

```
Times<-strptime(DATA$Time,format="%I:%M%p")

symbols(Times, y, circles=z, xaxt='n', inches=.4, fg="3", bg=(a), xlab="Times", ylab="y")

axis.POSIXct(1, at=Times, format="%I:%M%p")
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both approaches have the problem that in all likelihood your datetime format will not equal the values expressed just as a character vector like "5:00pm" even after coercion with the ">" comparison operator. To get the best advice you need to present str(DATA$Times) or dput(head(DATA$Times)) or class(Data$Times) . Generally plotting functions recognize either valid date or datetime classes or their numeric representation. If the ordering operation is not working, then it raises the question whether you have a proper class. But you appear to have an axis labeling that suggests a date-time format of some sort, and that we just need to figure out what class it really is.

Because you are creating a character vector from you Time column, you probably want to apply the restriction before you send the DATA$Time vector to strptime(). You still have not offered the requested clarifications, so I have no way to give tested or even very specific code, but you might be doing something like

```
Times<-strptime(DATA$Time[ as.POSIXlt(DATA$Time)$hour >= 17 & 
                           as.POSIXlt(DATA$Time)$hour <= 22 ] , 
                format="%I:%M%p")
```

Comment: Thanks, DWin. I've added what I plotted to the post above.